# Custom UserNamePasswordValidator not called

Tags: wcf, basic-authentication

I am trying to set up a WCF webservice with BasicHttpBinding and authentication using username/password. I made custom authentication class. However, it is never called (verified by debugging). This is my web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Compareware_WebApp.webservices.AuthenticationValidator, Compareware_WebApp" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Compareware_WebApp.webservices.Accounts">
    <endpoint address="/webservices/Accounts.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" name="BasicEndpoint"
      contract="Compareware_WebApp.webservices.IAccounts" />
  </service>
</services>
<client />
```

This is my authentication class:

```
namespace Compareware_WebApp.webservices
```

{

```
public class AuthenticationValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (null == userName || null == password)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (!Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
        {
            // This throws an informative fault to the client.
            throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
        }
    }
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, It never called, I also stuck in this position. Actually "TransportCredentialOnly" is checks the Username and password of the Windows, where your IIS is running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am also stuck in this problem, and I got a solution. If you want to call the `Validate` method of the `UserNamePasswordValidator` you must use the `TransportWithMessageCredential` security.

**NOTE:** You must host the WCF Services at the IIS server and have to enable SSL for your website, otherwise it will not work.

**WCF Server Web.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttp">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="TransportWithMessageCredential.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp" contract="TransportWithMessageCredential.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8080/WCFDemo"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wsHttpBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TransportWithMessageCredential.ServiceAuthanticator, TransportWithMessageCredential"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Service Authentication class**

```
 public class ServiceAuthanticator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                throw new FaultException("Please, Provide the username and password!!!");
            }

            if (userName != "abc" || password != "abc")
            {
                throw new FaultException("Sorry, Invalid username or password!!!");
            }
        }
    }
```

**WCF Client app.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://kalpesh-pc/WCFAuth/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Client Program to call the WCF Services**

```
try
{
    Service1Client objClient = new Service1Client();
    objClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "abc";
    objClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "abc";

    objClient.Open();
    string strData = objClient.GetData(10);
}
catch (FaultException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Happy Coding...

:)

Answer (score 0):

Transport, as far as I understand, requires HTTPS to encrypt credentials and throws an exception if there is no SSL. TransportCredentialOnly will send the credentials in plain text and unencrypted and is recommended for testing ONLY.
Therefore, your credentials are send via transport. So `<Transport>` tag must be adjusted, not `<Message>`.

The following works for me:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
</security>
```